# Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

Excuse my english, i am french. I have a error when i install fos User bundle of symfony2. 
I follow all instructions on this page : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

When i do this command : `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, i have a error. 
This is my error : 
`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in C:\P
rogram Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\Ecommerce\app\console on line 19`

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

It's late but it could help others people who are facing the same problem.
It seems like you are missing a component. I would suggest trying a "composer update" (I don't think it will work) in this case, i will be a bit more brutal and delete my vendor folder and reinstall everything with a "composer install".